# clock() - execution time for c function

Tags: c, performance, time, clock

I am trying to measure the execution time of a code block in C. I have something like this in my code:

```
clock_t begin, end;
double time_spent;
begin = clock();
ATL_dsymv(122,n,alfa,A,n,X,1,beta,Y,1);
end = clock();
time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf ("(%f seconds)",time_spent);
```

But it always returns: (0.000000 seconds). I tried the same thing on simpler code blocks like for's but it has the same result. What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use the same code but execute the timed part several million times.

Comment: About how long does the code take to run? What is the expected value, roughly?

Comment: the problem is that no matter what code block i have it only returns (0.000000 seconds)

Comment: What if you omit the division? Is `end - begin` already 0?

Comment: hmm..yes it is..but it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clock` usually has **very poor** resolution, on the order of 10 milliseconds. This is most likely your problem. If you're on a POSIX system, use `clock_gettime` with the `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` clock to get a high-resolution result. Other types of systems probably have system-specific ways to achieve the same.