# calculating run time of program in virtual machine

Tags: c, linux, virtual-machine, clock

I'm using below code to get the total time of my program.

```
clock_t start=clock();
//doing some work
clock_t end=clock();
printf("%f \n",(double)(end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

I'm running my program in virtual machine. It always shows me `0.000000`! Do you know why? Is it because of VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to print using an integer format specifier with a double value.

Try:

```
printf("%f \n",(double)(end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

EDIT: Just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15823156/2630790) that should fix your problem.

Comment: Sorry it was %f which prints double. Typo here.

Comment: Can you print `start` and `stop` separately to check if they are in fact the same value?

Comment: Have updated answer with link to fix.